# Move all instances outside parent div jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I quickly move the `.btn-2018` outside `.uc-articles-summary`. I need to apply this fix to all elements with the class `btn-2018`.

My attempted fix

```js
$('.btn-2018').each(function() {
  var $btn2018 = $('.uc-articles-summary > .btn-2018');
  $(this).parent().after($btn2018);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uc-articles-summary">
  <p>
    &nbsp; Platform magazine has been shortlisted for two national awards after...
  </p>
  <a class="btn-2018" title="Platform shortlisted for two national awards ..." href="/articles/platform-shortlisted-for-two-national-awards">read more »</a>
</div>
<div class="uc-articles-summary">
  <p>
    &nbsp; Another article explaining how to...
  </p>
  <a class="btn-2018" title="Platform shortlisted for two national awards ..." href="/articles/platform-shortlisted-for-two-national-awards">read more »</a>
</div>
<div class="uc-articles-summary">
  <p>
    &nbsp; You are braver than you believe, stronger than you feel, and...
  </p>
  <a class="btn-2018" title="Platform shortlisted for two national awards ..." href="/articles/platform-shortlisted-for-two-national-awards">read more »</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean by "move the .btn-2018 outside .uc-articles-summary"

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: @Justinas - it looks like the jQuery will add ALL buttons after the current buttons parent. This only looks to work because there is only one button atm.

Comment: I have added extra `div`s to the question to illustrate what I think is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your javascript to:

```
var $btn2018 = $(this);
$btn2018.closest('.uc-articles-summary').after($btn2018);
```

This way, you are telling jQuery to move the current element after it's own ancestor. I'm using `.closest` in case your button is deeply nested somewhere. If the button is always going to be an immediate child of `.uc-articles-summary`, then you can replace it with `.parent`.

```js
$('.btn-2018').each(function() {
  var $btn2018 = $(this);
  $btn2018.closest('.uc-articles-summary').after($btn2018);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uc-articles-summary">
  <p>
    &nbsp; Platform magazine has been shortlisted for two national awards after...
  </p>
  <a class="btn-2018" title="Platform shortlisted for two national awards ..." href="/articles/platform-shortlisted-for-two-national-awards">read more »</a>
</div>
<div class="uc-articles-summary">
  <p>
    &nbsp; Another article explaining how to...
  </p>
  <a class="btn-2018" title="Platform shortlisted for two national awards ..." href="/articles/platform-shortlisted-for-two-national-awards">read more »</a>
</div>
<div class="uc-articles-summary">
  <p>
    &nbsp; You are braver than you believe, stronger than you feel, and...
  </p>
  <a class="btn-2018" title="Platform shortlisted for two national awards ..." href="/articles/platform-shortlisted-for-two-national-awards">read more »</a>
</div>
```